# CodeKit: @codekit-prepend not working

Tags: codekit

I am trying to combine Javascript files via CodeKit using the in-file statement @codekit-prepend. Even though all the paths are correct and all the files exist CodeKit does not resolve the in-file statements. Is there anything missing?

[image: screenshot of my setup]

[image: codekit settings]

Comment: tried to include a file via drag & drop, does not work either...btw I am on Yosemite 10.10.2.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok so...it was me being stupid. it all worked well, i just looked in the wrong place. the combined file was inside the folder /min.